# Omission of Jesus Christ

Tags: lucifer

Although I have not read the comic book upon which the series is based, I have watched every episode of Lucifer on TV.  The main character, Lucifer, is a Christian concept; in the show, there are very frequent mentions of God as Lucifer's father.  However I have never heard any reference to Jesus Christ.  According to Christianity, Jesus is the son of God and the savior of humanity -- his absence here seems to be deliberate.  Can anyone explain this omission?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter - but I suspect that its because it sounds like you have an opinion that Jesus somehow *should* be mentioned rather than its a particularly strange omission.  After all, in the Christian tradition - Christ is one part of 'God' along with the Father and Holy Spirit - so in that respect Christ is mentioned no more or less than the Father.  Not having seem the show - can you explain *why* its a strange omission from your perspective?

Comment: iandotkelly:  See my comment posted below.

Comment: "there are very frequent mentions of God as Lucifer's father" Note that this is something the majority of Christian denominations vehemently deny. (I believe either Jehova's Witness or LDS might believe this; my recollection is fuzzy. But most denominations of Christianity deny that these are legitimate denominations of Christianity.)

Comment: For a twist, "Lucifer" appears exactly once in the Bible, referring to the King of Babylon (Isaiah 14:12). Lucifer means "morning star", literally meaning the planet Venus in the sky, and figuratively meaning a human king. Jesus is also called "morning star" (Revelation 22:16), as he is the king of kings (Revelation 19:16), and this is the only other time "morning star" is used this way. From this perspective, Jesus _is_ Lucifer :)

Comment: @BrianS That's a variant of the "etymological fallacy", FYI

Comment: What if the setting is prior to 10BC, or an alternate universe where Jesus's first coming has not occurred yet?

Comment: @eques, No. The etymological fallacy is holding the present-day meaning of a word as having similar meaning to the historical meaning. My statement is entirely in the context of the Bible. In fact, calling Lucifer the devil is extremely far from the historical meaning of the word. At the time, "lucifer" was a word to poetically refer to a king, and Jesus was the king of kings.

Comment: @BrianS I believe eques is referring to your comparison between Christ and Lucifer as the fallacy. While it may not be an etymological fallacy, it is certainly a fallacy of some kind. Whether the passage in Isaiah is referring to Satan or the king of Babylon (or perhaps even both), it is obviously not referring to Christ. Nor does Christ have any of the attributes of the word used as it is used today. (Perhaps eques meant that your fallacy was assigning an old meaning to a modern term that means something completely different now.)

Comment: In charecter, I'd assume that Lucifer just didn't consider him important enough to mention. His ego *is* somewhat of a ongoing joke. Also, the comic book series and show are tonally very different, just with some similar charecters. The comic was pretty serious IIRC

Comment: @Jessica Can you explain why Jesus should be mentioned? Is there **anything** in the mythos that requires the mention of Jesus? Is it in any way **necessary** or even **meaningful** — when considering the TV-show's storyline(s), characters' development and similar — to include Jesus? **Christ** is meaningful and important to **Christ**ians, that is true. But in what way is the Christ character important to this production?

Comment: He is. But the show is called "Supernatural".

Comment: @BrianS that's why I said it's a variant. It's a fallacy insofar as you are implying perhaps facetiously that Christ is Lucifer (association of persons) based on how the term "lucifer" is historically used. Hence your association is ignoring how the term "Lucifer" presently is used to refer almost exclusively to the devil. As an aside, this same idea but used in reverse is used as an anti-Catholic attack because "lucifer" is used in some Latin texts to refer to Christ, but anti-Catholics assume it means the devil

Comment: I too haven't *heard* any references to Jesus in Lucifer, but I've *seen* one. The mystical coin that Lucifer had until season 1, episode 13 that provided the bearer one-time passage to or from Hell had an image of Jesus on the cross on one side.

Answer (score 41):

I think there are two things going on here, one thematic, and one a production concern.

The idea of the show is about Lucifer and his relationship with God. That relationship and that story played out *long* before Jesus was born. In that sense, bringing up Jesus would merely be a distraction. Since the show seems to align pretty nicely with traditional he Christian theology, from Lucifer's standpoint, Jesus was just his Father taking physical form on Earth. It's unlikely that Lucifer considers that period of time particularly significant. What he's more focused on is the image of himself that built up *afterwards*, over the centuries, which is why he abandonded Hell.

On top of that, fictional shows that are based on real-world theology are usually very careful to avoid being *too* on the nose about it. You see this not only with *Lucifer* but also similar "modern fantasy" shows like *Supernatural*. What the show's creators are trying to do is to carefully avoid bringing up anything that would cause "too much" controversy about their show, and cause a public relations issue.

The basic existence of angels and demons, for example, is generic enough that it's not too problematic to include them in a show that's obviously fiction. The idea of an all-powerful God is a bit sketchier, but as He's generally spoken of in vague terms, it's also not a big deal.

Having an on-screen character that is explicitly the Christian devil, with his traditional fallen angel backstory, is really pushing the line. To those people for whom Christianity is a true theology, such a different, and largely comedic, depiction of a part of their faith could be considered offensive. (I know of at least a handful of devout Christians who really dislike the premise of the show as "humanizing" and "trivializing" the concept of Hell.)

The intentional avoiding of mentioning Jesus is almost certainly done to avoid crossing over that line any further than it is. You would need to somehow fit Jesus -- the most important figure in Christianity -- into this show that takes almost nothing else about its own mythology seriously. That's probably a can of worms the writers don't want to open up.

---

Having said all that, I feel like there's been at least a couple of times that Jesus's existence on Earth was *mentioned* by Lucifer, though not by named. Again, it would not have been anything the show would want to focus on, but I don't think they are acting as if it *never* happened.

Comment: Concerning the absence of Jesus references in the Lucifer TV show, I already knew that Neil Gaiman is Jewish, and have since learned that his family became Scientologists.  In an interview cited at http://forward.com/culture/369715/the-secret-jewish-history-of-neil-gaiman-and-american-gods/ Gaiman said: “My family became Jewish Scientologists, which I would say is different. They got no less Jewish.”  I  am not a Christian, and am not condemning the TV show for not including Christ; I think that the omission is due to Gaiman's personal perspective.

Comment: that is possible; Gaiman has a writing credit on every episode so far but I don't know how much he's personally involved in the show (vs being credited because he invented the characters). The show already veered quite far from the source material so I think if they wanted to put Jesus in they would have, regardless of Gaiman's beliefs.

Comment: FYI, there is another current Neil Gaiman TV series: __[American Gods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Gods_(TV_series))__. Jesus did [make an appearance there](https://io9.gizmodo.com/american-gods-jesus-shows-what-happens-when-a-god-becom-1796255952).

Comment: That's true. It's also worth noting that broadcast network like FOX is also going to be far more gun-shy than a premium cable channel like Starz when it comes to what content may or may not be considered offensive.

Comment: "Since the show seems to align pretty nicely with traditional he [sic] Christian theology..." A better phrasing might be "draws heavily from," as I doubt that it aligns with Christian theology very much if Christ is not even mentioned. ;) Christian theology pretty explicitly emphasizes Christ's involvement in all things.

Comment: "*carefully avoid bringing up anything that would cause "too much" controversy about their show*"  An older example would be the show *Stargate SG1*, where the antagonist Goa'uld took on the form of all the major mythologies' dieties except Jehovah/Allah, Jesus and the Hindus (presumably because elephants and blue paint were too expensive).

Comment: "That relationship and that story played out long before Jesus was born" "Jesus was just his Father taking physical form on Earth" From the perspective of Christian theology, these statements are false. God the father and Christ the son are two distinct entities, but one 'substance'. The viewpoint of these quotes are specifically the Arian heresy, which was condemned in 325 at the Council of Nicea and died out in the 700s or so. The orthodox Christian view is that "he [Jesus] was in the beginning with God." (John 1:2, NAB)

Comment: @jpmc26 If Lucifer is going to be on Earth, which for most of the show he is, then he can't rightly interact with Christ without the second coming of Christ, which needless to say would be a significant plot shift for everyone.

Comment: Actually, the judeo-christian god makes physical presence in Supernatural.

Answer (score 9):

A straightforward explanation is that the comic book the series (3 series building upon each other, but written by 3 different authors actually) is based on also does not mention Jesus Christ in any significant way.

I do not think the comic authors would be as worried about offending people since the comics just don't have the visibility of a TV show.

That leaves the in-universe explanation, and I think the answer by @KutuluMike has it just right: Lucifer's beef is with God, the concept of predetermination, and of subservient worship, and he rejects them outright. He is not much interested in the finer theologic points that humans have made about these concepts where Jesus might be relevant.

Lucifer became what he is because of events that played out *long before* the time of Christ.

Answer (score 7):

There are many religions beyond Christianity which believe in a "God" and a "Lucifer", where Lucifer's primary occupation is to reign over a "hell".

Suggesting that Christianity has these two characters, then inferring that other characters from the Christian perspective should also be present is a logical fallacy - projection.

Unless there is other evidence in the TV show that the show subscribes to a Christian perspective then there is no reason to believe that the show must, or should, contain other characters from the Christian perspective.

As designed, the show appeals to people of many faiths.  Were they to include a Christ figure, it would suddenly not apply to Muslims, Jewish, agnostic, and audience members of many other religions.

By keeping the show very restricted to an underworld character and a limited view of a deity, it has much more broad appeal.

Comment: My observation about the omission of Christ in the TV show 'Lucifer' is linked to my much earlier question about the presence of 'God's wife.'  In the Bible, it is Adam who has a supernatural wife, Lilith the demon, before his pairing with Eve.  I am unaware of any mention of God's wife in actual Biblical texts--even as the mother of the angels.  In Genesis, God created everything--all by Himself--although angels are not specified.  I assume that He, alone, also created the angels.  Gaiman's Lucifer, even if largely based upon Christian theology, is not strictly faithful to Christian tenets.

Answer (score 6):

## The show has a much wider base for its lore than just Christianity

Jessica, you say...

> According to Christianity...

Well, Christianity is a **human** cult. All religions are just that: **human** inventions.

This show is not about what humans believe. This show treats the divine and the demonic as a reality that does not slavishly adhere to what humans believe. And the show frequently makes it plain that what humans believe is very rarely accurate (especially regarding the ruler of Hell).

To add to that, Christianity is only one of the cults that are based on the Abrahamic god and the surrounding lore. Judaism does not recognise Jesus as the Messiah or even as a prophet. And while some branches of Judaism recognises [Satan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satan#Judaism), none recognise the [Devil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil). Islam recognises the Devil, and sees Jesus as a lesser prophet, but not as the Messiah. Yet all these religions — and their sub-versions — are based on the same lore as the show.

So to summarise: yes, **Christ** is important to **Christians**... but this show bases its lore on concepts and characters that are far wider than only the Christian mythology. And in any case the show does not consider any particular religion as being rock solid canon and allows itself to adapt that lore as it sees fit.

Comment: I'd also add that Lucifer is not a Christian invention nor of Christian origin - Lucifer is from the old testiment.